# dotnet test run crashes due to connection forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: c#, .net, xunit.net

The unit tests on a C# test project run correctly on my machine but fail when running on a VM. The code, OS (Windows 10), architecture (x64) and .NET SDK (6.0.408) are all the same. The project builds successfully, and then I get the following runtime error:

```
Test Run Aborted with error System.Exception: One or more errors occurred.
 ---> System.Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Note that there is no application server here. It looks like xUnit.net sets up a socket for running the tests asynchronously.

I suspect this might have something to do with the network policies on the VM, but I'm not sure. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: A unit test that needs a working remote host? Isn't really a _unit_ test, is it? But let's not be nitpicky: did you check firewall settings?

Comment: Well that's why I'm confused - there is no remote host. Checking Wireshark it looks like there is a TCP socket opened on the loopback address and then after the tests run there is a RST flag sent.

Comment: Is there a Virus Scanner installed? I once had an issue where we tested the availability of our servers by opening a connection. Trend Micro Scanner happily responded with honey pot hosting on any port that wasn't otherwise bound.